# Why doesn't the webpage appear? What is missing in my code?

Tags: c#, browser, navigateurl

I'm trying to make my own webbrowser with C#, 
my wpf application seems to be correct. but it's still missing something.
the webpage doesn't appear. :s
Does someone have an idea?

Here's my code in C# :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        web.NavigateToString (textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For WPF, the XAML may be helpful

Comment: There seems to be a closing brace missing.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand, you are instantiating a new `WebBrowser` control in code and you aren't adding it as a control to the actual form. You'd better add the control in design view and just do the method call in the code.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the WebBrowser, try adding a third line:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
Content = web; // extra line
web.NavigateToString (textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is your address bar, it won't work. NavigateToString will interpret what's in your textbox as literal HTML.

```
web.NavigateToString (textBox1.Text);
```

should be

```
web.Source = new Uri(textBox1.Text, UriKind.Absolute);
```